# How do I fix or work around a circular dependency in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, dependencies, dependency-management

Suppose I have three Javascript files:

controller.js:

```js
require("cleanhouse.js");

function start() { 
  console.log("Housecleaning has begun!");
  cleanhouse() 
}

function finish() { 
  console.log("Housecleaning done!") 
}
```

cleanhouse.js:

```js
require("cleankitchen.js");

function cleanhouse() { cleankitchen() }
```

cleankitchen.js:

```js
require("controller.js");

function cleankitchen() { finish() }
```

When I call start() it should print "Housecleaning has begun!" and then "Housecleaning done!".

But there's a circular dependency of require()'s there. Namely, controller.js requires cleanhouse.js which requires cleankitchen.js which requires controller.js.

How can I fix or work around that, subject to the following constraints?

1. Keep cleanhouse() in its own file.
2. Keep cleankitchen() in its own file.
3. Keep the cleanhouse() and cleankitchen() functions pristine.

In particular the cleanhouse() and cleankitchen() functions should not have to deal with callbacks or Promises or event emitters or anything. Some boilerplate in cleanhouse.js and cleankitchen.js would be ok but the functions themselves should stay as written above. Complicating the code in controller.js is ok.

Comment: For some reason I still cannot process what the heck is going on 

Answer (score 0):

I've discussed this with Javascript expert friends and I think there are two main possible answers:

1. If the finish() function can be separated from the rest of the code in controller.js then that's the simplest way to break the dependency cycle.
2. If not, then I should drop the constraint that the cleankitchen() function stays exactly as written. Instead, cleankitchen() should get the finish() function passed to it as a parameter instead of doing a require() to get finish() as a library function.